# Solving linear inequalities and expressing in interval notation...

Tags: inequality, arithmetic

I have a set of problems for my algebra class dealing with expressing  linear inequalities in interval notation. I get the solution but I'm not sure how to express the infinity, here's an example.

$$-56 < 6x - 2 < -20$$

And I get the answer as $-9$, but I am required to enter interval notation as, for example:

$$(-\text{inf}, 6)$$

Yet when I enter $(-9, \text{inf})$, that is incorrect. Is there something I am missing? It's happening quite often with this problem set and I don't know what else I can enter besides "inf" if it's the right endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$
\begin{array}{rcccl}
  -56 &<& 6x-2 &<& -20\\
  \iff -54 &<& 6x &<& -18\\
  \iff -9 &<& x &<& -3
\end{array}
$$
so the solution set is the interval $(-9,-3)$, you should enter that. Note that $\infty$ is not always an endpoint.

Comment: It does not seem to think that is correct. I see your math, but the system won't accept it.